# Taking count of unique Campaign IDs matching their Case ID in different google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

[image: Column B has repetitive campaign Ids against same Case IDs]

I want to get the count of unique Campaigns Ids against case ID in other sheet with the name "SFDC_Dump".

[image: Main Sheet where i want to bring the Count of Unique campaigns IDS matching Case Ids]

Comment: Just asking, but why is this question tagged as `Excel` ?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with some example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the formula `COUNTUNIQUEIFS()`

It's exactly the same as `COUNTIFS` but will only count each distinct value once.

Comment: Is there a way to take all the values in CSV in a call matching that criteria? For eg Column C in Campaign_Dump file in CSV for one unique Case IDs.

Answer (score 0):

**VBA method**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowSource As Long, LastRowDestination As Long, i As Long, y As Long, Counter As Long
    Dim CaseID As String, CampaignID As String
    Dim rngCaseID As Range, rngCampaignID As Range

    'Set the workshhets (change sheet names)
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSource = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    'Loop the sources sheet
    With wsSource

        LastRowSource = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRowSource

            CaseID = .Range("A" & i).Value
            CampaignID = .Range("B" & i).Value

            Set rngCaseID = .Range("A2:A" & LastRowSource)
            Set rngCampaignID = .Range("B2:B" & LastRowSource)

            Counter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngCaseID, CaseID, rngCampaignID, CampaignID)

            'Paste into destination sheet
            With wsDestination

                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), CaseID, .Range("B:B"), CampaignID) = 0 Then

                    LastRowDestination = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                    .Range("A" & LastRowDestination).Value = CaseID
                    .Range("B" & LastRowDestination).Value = CampaignID
                    .Range("C" & LastRowDestination).Value = Counter
                End If

            End With

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Excel Method:**

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)`

Comment: Thank you for your help however, I wanted to populate it without using scripts.